# OpenVPN GUI keeps disconnecting/reconnecting on Windows 7

Tags: windows, openvpn

I'm having an interesting issue with Windows 7 where several customer's OpenVPN clients are constantly connecting & disconnecting to my Ubuntu 10.04 LTS server. I'm able to connect to the same server with OSX, iPhone, iPad, Android but for some reason some of the Windows 7 clients are having issues.

The client version is OpenVPN 2.1.3 i686-pc-mingw32 [SSL] [LZO2] [PKCS11] built on Aug 20 2010

From inspecting the logs on the client, the following line is suspicious:

```
Route addition via IPAPI succeeded [adaptive]
```

On the server, the following line is also suspicious:

```
CTRL: Ignored a SET LINK INFO packet with real ACCMs!
```

I haven't been able to find any reason why the client would be having issues only in Windows 7 and I'm not sure why the server would ignore its set link info packet.

The OpenVPN client in Windows 7 has the following:

```
Sun Aug 14 23:39:04 2011 TEST ROUTES: 1/1 succeeded len=0 ret=1 a=0 u/d=up
Sun Aug 14 23:39:04 2011 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe ADD 212.117.170.76 MASK 255.255.255.255 192.168.2.1
Sun Aug 14 23:39:04 2011 ROUTE: CreateIpForwardEntry succeeded with dwForwardMetric1=100 and dwForwardType=4
Sun Aug 14 23:39:04 2011 Route addition via IPAPI succeeded [adaptive]
Sun Aug 14 23:39:04 2011 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe ADD 0.0.0.0 MASK 128.0.0.0 10.24.125.1
Sun Aug 14 23:39:04 2011 ROUTE: CreateIpForwardEntry succeeded with dwForwardMetric1=30 and dwForwardType=4
Sun Aug 14 23:39:04 2011 Route addition via IPAPI succeeded [adaptive]
Sun Aug 14 23:39:04 2011 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe ADD 128.0.0.0 MASK 128.0.0.0 10.24.125.1
Sun Aug 14 23:39:04 2011 ROUTE: CreateIpForwardEntry succeeded with dwForwardMetric1=30 and dwForwardType=4
Sun Aug 14 23:39:04 2011 Route addition via IPAPI succeeded [adaptive]
Sun Aug 14 23:39:04 2011 Initialization Sequence Completed
Sun Aug 14 23:39:05 2011 Connection reset, restarting [-1]
Sun Aug 14 23:39:05 2011 TCP/UDP: Closing socket
Sun Aug 14 23:39:05 2011 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe DELETE 212.117.170.76 MASK 255.255.255.255 192.168.2.1
Sun Aug 14 23:39:05 2011 Route deletion via IPAPI succeeded [adaptive]
```

The logs on the server say this:

```
Aug 16 06:52:51 pppd[27924]: Connect: ppp27 <--> /dev/pts/28
Aug 16 06:52:57 pppd[27924]: Unsupported protocol 'IPv6 Control Protocol' (0x8057) received
Aug 16 06:52:58 pptpd[27923]: CTRL: Ignored a SET LINK INFO packet with real ACCMs!
Aug 16 06:53:00 pppd[27924]: local  IP address 10.42.124.1
Aug 16 06:53:00 pppd[27924]: remote IP address 10.42.124.34
Aug 16 06:53:01 pppd[27924]: MPPE 128-bit stateless compression enabled
Aug 16 06:53:03 pppd[27924]: MPPE disabled
Aug 16 06:53:03 pppd[27924]: Connect time 0.1 minutes.
Aug 16 06:53:03 pppd[27924]: Sent 390 bytes, received 540 bytes.
Aug 16 06:53:09 pppd[27924]: Connection terminated.
Aug 16 06:53:09 pppd[27924]: write: Bad file descriptor (9)
Aug 16 06:53:09 pppd[27924]: Modem hangup
Aug 16 06:53:09 pppd[27924]: Exit.
```

Comment: I would suggest you setting output verbosity to 5 (`verb 5`) and try again to see what happens.